# On Image Drawing Save

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, drawing

I have created a small application in C#, in which I draw a rectangle when the mouse is moved.

However, when the form is minimized or maximized, the drawing is erased. Also, when I draw a second time, the drawing of the first rectangle is erased.

How can I solve this problem? Here is the code that I currently have:

```
   int X, Y;
    Graphics G;
    Rectangle Rec;
    int UpX, UpY, DwX, DwY;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //G = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        //Rec = new Rectangle(X, Y, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    }


    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        UpX = e.X;
        UpY = e.Y;
        //Rec = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        //this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DwX = e.X;
        DwY = e.Y;

        Rec = new Rectangle(UpX, UpY, DwX - UpX, DwY - UpY);
        Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            G.DrawRectangle(pen, Rec);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Draws the rectangle as the mouse moves
            Rec = new Rectangle(UpX, UpY, e.X - UpX, e.Y - UpY);
            Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                G.DrawRectangle(pen, Rec);
            }
            G.Save();
            pictureBox1.SuspendLayout();
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();

        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Update();            
    }
```

Comment: You Don't Need To Capitalize Every Single Word.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your drawings are getting erased is because you're drawing into a `Graphics` object you obtained by calling the `CreateGraphics` method. In particular, this line of your code is incorrect:

```
 Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
```

As you've discovered, whenever the form is *repainted* (which happens when it is maximized, minimized, covered by another object on the screen, or in a number of other possible situations), everything that you've drawn into that temporary `Graphics` object is lost. The form completely repaints itself with its internal painting logic; it's completely forgotten about what you temporarily drew on top of it.

The *correct* way to draw persistent images in WinForms is to override the [`OnPaint` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) of the control that you want to draw onto (or, you could also handle the [`Paint` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx)). So, if you wanted to paint onto your form, you would place your drawing code into the following method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Call the base class first
    base.OnPaint(e);

    // Then insert your custom drawing code
    Rec = new Rectangle(UpX, UpY, DwX - UpX, DwY - UpY);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, Rec);
    }
}
```

And to trigger a re-paint, you just call the [`Invalidate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) in any of the mouse events (`MouseDown`, `MouseMove`, and `MouseUp`):

```
this.Invalidate();
```

Note, however, that there's absolutely no reason to call the [`Update` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) in the `Paint` event handler. All that calling the `Update` method does is force the control to repaint itself. But that is already happening when the `Paint` event gets raised!